# Sumar el resultado de un campo con el mismo segmento usando "Union all"

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente intento usar dos consultas diferentes y unirlas con "union all", también me gustaría sumar los campos.

Esta es mi consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría es que los segmentos repetidos se sumaran y no quedaran repetidos y un resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más simple es usar tu consulta actual como una tabla derivada o una CTE.

Como tabla derivada:

```
SELECT  Segmento,
        SUM(SubTotal) SubTotal,
        SUM(Utilidad) Utilidad,
        SUM(Margen) Margen,
        SUM(Notas_Vend) Notas_Vend,
        SUM(Art_Vend) Art_Vend
FROM (
        select ..... -- el resto de tu consulta actual, sin el order by
     ) Z
GROUP BY Segmento
ORDER BY SUM(SubTotal) DESC
;
```

Como CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    select ..... -- el resto de tu consulta actual, sin el order by
)
SELECT  Segmento,
        SUM(SubTotal) SubTotal,
        SUM(Utilidad) Utilidad,
        SUM(Margen) Margen,
        SUM(Notas_Vend) Notas_Vend,
        SUM(Art_Vend) Art_Vend
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Segmento
ORDER BY SUM(SubTotal) DESC
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono perfecto.